# SVG won't display unless previously loaded in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I embed a svg like: `<img src="http://example.com/path/to/picture.svg" />`

Displays fine in IE, but does not render in Chrome (Version 34.0.1847.131)

However, if I then load `http://example.com/path/to/picture.svg`

directly, it renders fine- and strangly reloading the original page then does display the graphic.

Using  renders the first time around, but since I am using these for links... would be best if  can work

Comment: Does the server respond with the correct content-type?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, /etc/nginx/mime.types has: image/svg+xml svg svgz;

Comment: Any chance your SVG file contains references to other files (images, stylesheets, etc.) required for it to render?  Those shouldn't normally be loaded in `<img>` tags (for security reasons), but I've found that if Chrome has the content in cache from opening the SVG directly it will load the external files, making it look temporarily like the SVG works fine as `<img>`.

Comment: Ah ok, these SVGs are embedding bitmap data, they aren't as vector... will try to get them as vector (which is why I'm using SVG in the first place) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to be a bug in chrome when using SVGs with embedded bitmap data. Using pure vector-based SVGs works fine

Comment: Hey, just ran into the same problem, how did you convert it ?

Comment: I don't remember... sorry :\ Probably somehow with Adobe illustrator :)